# How to load two images onto a zynq zedboard

Tags: opencv, fpga, xilinx, vivado, image-stitching

I'm trying to stitch two images on fpga using xilinx zedboard zynq7000. I couldn't find any material on how to dump two images onto the board and then get the output placing the images side to side. Any leads are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm going step by step and will later look about how to compute homography etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That board has arm processors, typically running linux. So at least you won't have any problems in getting images into the board, either with gigabit ethernet, or on sd card, or on memory stick in usb otg port. You don't really want to implement that channel yourself on fpga side, it would be just a waste of time.

To process images using fpga part (assuming that's the point of the task), you'll have your fpga-hw part connected to arm system via AXI interface, and memory-map it into linux application's address space.

You don't need entire images saved into fpga hw memory blocks, as probably pics will be too large to fit into available fpga resources, and because fpga can access linux side memory (big sdram) via fpga-to-sdram bridge.

Comment: Hey, can you provide some links to go about linux and opencv with the board. Thanks

Comment: @Electrix, I'm in the other camp (Altera), so google it yourself. Some first links could be like: https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp1167.pdf